# react router v4 input component losing focus while typing

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router-v4

I'm using react router v4 and using the render prop to load up a settings component that has a dynamic input (a value prop based on the state with an onChange handler). When I load the component without using react router, typing into the input field is dynamic, and changes state as you type. But when I use react router, each character press re-renders the entire settings component, causing the input field to lose focus. Not sure why this is happening, since I'm using the render prop instead of the component prop on the `<Route />` component. Any help would be appreciated!

My App Component:

```
import React, { Component, Fragment } from "react";
import { BrowserRouter, Route, Switch } from "react-router-dom";
import Home from "../Home/Home";
import Header from "../Header/Header";
import AppSettings from "../AppSettings/AppSettings";
import NotFound from "../NotFound/NotFound";
import { secsToMs, minsToMs, msToTime } from "../../helpers";
import "./App.css";

class App extends Component {
    state = {
        settings: {
            time: {
                break: minsToMs(5),
                relax: minsToMs(15),
                work: minsToMs(25)
            },
            trackLength: 2,
            autoplay: true
        },
        defaultSettings: {
            time: {
                break: minsToMs(5),
                relax: minsToMs(15),
                work: minsToMs(25)
            },
            trackLength: 4,
            autoplay: false
        },
        time: minsToMs(25),
        totalTime: minsToMs(25),
        timerPlaying: false,
        track: {
            tasksCompleted: 0,
            breaksCompleted: 0,
            timerName: "work"
        }
    };

    updateSettings = (key, updatedSetting) => {
        let settings = { ...this.state.settings };
        settings.time[key] = updatedSetting;
        this.setState({ settings });
    };

    //...other App methods

    render() {
        const MainAppContent = ({ location }) => (
            <Fragment>
                <Header track={this.state.track} location={location} />
                <Home
                    timerPlaying={this.state.timerPlaying}
                    totalTime={this.state.totalTime}
                    time={this.state.time}
                    track={this.state.track}
                    trackLength={this.state.settings.trackLength}
                    startTimer={this.startTimer}
                    pauseTimer={this.pauseTimer}
                    resetTimer={this.resetTimer}
                    skipTimer={this.skipTimer}
                />
                <AppSettings
                    settings={this.state.settings}
                    updateSettings={this.updateSettings}
                    restoreDefaultSettings={this.restoreDefaultSettings}
                />
            </Fragment>
        );

        const SettingsAppContent = ({ location }) => (
            <Fragment>
                <Header track={this.state.track} location={location} />
                <AppSettings
                    settings={this.state.settings}
                    updateSettings={this.updateSettings}
                    restoreDefaultSettings={this.restoreDefaultSettings}
                />
            </Fragment>
        );

        return (
            <main className="App">
                <BrowserRouter>
                    <Switch>
                        <Route exact path="/" component={MainAppContent} />
                        <Route
                            path="/settings"
                            render={props => <SettingsAppContent {...props} />}
                        />
                        <Route component={NotFound} />
                    </Switch>
                </BrowserRouter>
            </main>
        );
    }
}

export default App;
```

My AppSettings Component:

```
import React, { Component, Fragment } from "react";
import RangeSlider from "../RangeSlider/RangeSlider";
import { minsToMs } from "../../helpers";
import "./AppSettings.css";

class Settings extends Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <Fragment>
                <h1>Settings</h1>
                {Object.keys(this.props.settings.time).map(key => (
                    <RangeSlider
                        name={key}
                        key={key}
                        time={this.props.settings.time[key]}
                        updateSettings={this.props.updateSettings}
                    />
                ))}
                <button onClick={this.props.restoreDefaultSettings}>
                    Revert to Default
                </button>
            </Fragment>
        );
    }
}

export default Settings;
```

My Input Component:

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import { msToTime, minsToMs } from "../../helpers";
import "./RangeSlider.css";

class RangeSlider extends Component {
    onSettingsChange = e => {
        let rangeValue = parseInt(e.currentTarget.value);
        if (rangeValue > 60) {
            rangeValue = 60;
        } else if (rangeValue < 1 || rangeValue === NaN) {
            rangeValue = 1;
        }

        let rangeValueMs = minsToMs(rangeValue);
        let key = e.currentTarget.name;
        let updatedSetting = rangeValueMs;

        const updatedSettings = {
            ...this.props.settings,
            [key]: rangeValueMs
        };

        console.log("updatedSettings", updatedSettings);

        this.props.updateSettings(key, updatedSetting);
    };

    render() {
        const { name, time } = this.props;

        return (
            <div>
                <input
                    type="number"
                    min="1"
                    max="60"
                    value={msToTime(time).m}
                    className="text-box"
                    name={name}
                    onChange={this.onSettingsChange}
                />
            </div>
        );
    }
}

export default RangeSlider;
```

Comment: This turned out to not be a react-router issue. I was building out my components inside the `render()` function inside my App component. This caused the child components to be completely rebuilt on any rerender.

Comment: How did you resolve this?